# Input field limit 9 char and after 3 char automaticly ads "-"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input id="myText" type="text" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXX" /></input>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myText").value.substr(0, 9).match(/.{1,3}/g).join("-");
</script>
```

Comment: You need to set the value after updating the string, use `....value = ....replace()`

Comment: still nothing, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your current JavaScript. First, your script will only run once when the page is loaded, meaning any input you enter into `myText` after that will never be processed. Consider binding to an event of `myText` - for example, the `onkeyup` event.

Another problem is that your JavaScript doesn't take into account existing dashes when splitting the value of `myText` into 3-character parts - this results in undesirable behaviour, where more and more dashes will be added to the value, at seemingly random positions.

Lastly, as mentioned by Tushar in the comments, you need to set the value of `myText` to the new, processed value you create. Otherwise this value ends up being unused and discarded, and your code appears to do nothing.

Putting this all together, the fixed code might look like:

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById("myText");

textInput.onkeyup = function()
{
    var dashlessInput = textInput.value.replace(/-/g, "");
    textInput.value = dashlessInput.substr(0, 9).match(/.{1,3}/g).join("-");
};
```

```html
<input id="myText" type="text" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXX" /></input>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

*For future reference - try to clearly state what your question by explaining what you want to achieve, and specifically indicating what problems you're facing. This way, you're more likely to attract good answers rather than downvotes.*

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help out!